# Using python logging with str.format

Tags: python, logging, string-formatting

I like `str.format` - the syntax is clean, and it's feature rich. I use it almost everywhere.

Unfortunately `logging` uses the old string interpolation (`%` operator). If given a `str.format` style string, it just fails.

```
>>> logging.error("foo {}", 1)
[...]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Of course, I can just format beforehand:

```
>>> logging.error("foo {}".format(1))
```

But this is not ideal for larger objects with lots of debug logging calls, for performance reasons.

Is there a way to properly use `str.format` style with `logging`?

Comment: `str.format` : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format. I wonder whether there is any option like you mentioned above for `str.format`